# How do I get event invites as calendar app notifications

Tags: ios, icloud, calendar

My wife has an iCloud account and we use calendar events to highlight family staying over or working from home days, medical appointments etc.

I have an iCloud account. My wife invites me to an event she creates and I receive an email. I would expect this to come directly in the calendar app inbox.

Currently I have to open email click 'accept' which opens an iCloud url  and I have to accept again for wife to see I have accepted. I then have to go back to email and open the attached .ics file and choose add to calendar for it to appear in my calendar.

My wife and I agreed to use an alias for iCloud email as the invitee address in this scenario I never receive emails of notifications.

I've contacted apple support and have a case number but at this point no solution. I'm appealing to the masses for help.

Thanks

P.s both using iOS 12 on iPhone 8+ and iPhone 8. Also have iPad Pro 1st Gen also on iOS 12.

Comment: who's calendar are you using ? Google ?

Comment: We are both iCloud/iOS only

Comment: We can both create events and send them to each other. We get emails. But we don't get calendar.app notifications and invitation does not appear in the app's inbox. As I said above the work to accept the meeting and to ensure it's a) in my calendar and b) wife can see I have accepted it in her calendar is quite frankly ludicrous.

Answer (score 1):

There may be an issue with the actual calendars that you are displaying, and the default calendars associated with each device?

I would check 2 things.

First, the default calendar on your iOS device. Settings -> Calendar -> default Calendar (ensure it is iCloud)

Second, ensure that the calendar you are seeing in Calendar is your iCloud. In Calendar, tap “Calendars” at the bottom, and ensure iCloud is checked off

Now when you create events, they should default to your iCloud account, and you should be able to add invitees and see their RSVP status

Hope this helps!